# For $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $|a| \geq |b+c|, |b| \geq |c+a|, |c| \geq |a+b|$ prove then $a+b+c = 0$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

> For $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $|a| \geq |b+c|, |b| \geq |c+a|, |c|
>  \geq |a+b|$ prove then $a+b+c = 0$

---

Solution:
$$
|a| + |b| + |c| \geq |b+c| + |c+a| + |a+b| \geq 0
$$
and
$$0 \leq |a+b+c|\leq |a+b| + |c| \leq |a| + |b| + |c|$$
so we have 
$$0 \leq |a+b+c| \geq 0 $$
$$ |a+b+c|= 0 \iff a+b+c =0 $$

I need check my solution. 
Many thanks!

Comment: From $0 \leq |a+b+c| \geq 0$ it doesn't follow that $|a+b+c|=0$...

Comment: Yes, i agree @amrsa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint:** Square each of the $| ..|$  inequality and consider $f(a) = a^2 + (2b+2c)a + (b+c)^2$. Show that $f(a) \ge 0$.

Comment: I tried understand the first intuition of $f(a)$?Where is she from?

Comment: @Blabla: After square all $3$ inequalities and simplify both sides you will arrive at $f(a)$.

Comment: Many thanks, I checked your hint, but we need show that $f(a) \leq 0$ ? When I compute of $\delta = 4(b+c)^{2} - 4(b+c)^{2}  = 0$ But I am not sure how to show depending from $a+b+c = 0 $

Comment: @Blabla: Think about it a little bit more and you can "see" the answer. If I wrote down all the steps, you would not learn a thing and no fun at all. Better keep it a little secretive. Note that: $f(a) \le 0$ is already there.

Comment: Ok, next  we have $f(-(b+c)/2) = 0 $

Comment: Please, hint for next step :

Comment: @Blabla: $f(a) = ( ...+ ...+...)^2$. What's inside ?

Comment: $ f(a) = (a+b+c)^{2} $

Comment: @Blabla: Can you put it "together" and see the answer?

Comment: Ok, I have it, many thanks @DeepSea

Answer (score 0):

We have:
$$a^2\geq(b+c)^2,$$
$$b^2\geq(a+c)^2$$ and $$c^2\geq(a+b)^2$$ or
$$(a-b-c)(a+b+c)\geq0,$$ $$(b-a-c)(a+b+c)\geq0$$ and $$(c-a-b)(a+b+c)\geq0.$$
Now, for $a+b+c>0$ we obtain:
$$a-b-c\geq0,$$ $$b-a-c\geq0$$ and $$c-a-b\geq0,$$ which gives
$$a-b-c+b-a-c\geq0$$ or
$$c\leq0.$$
Similarly, $b\leq0$ and $a\leq0,$ which gives
$$a+b+c\leq0,$$ which is a contradiction.

By the same way we'll obtain a contradiction for $a+b+c<0.$

Thus, $a+b+c=0$ and we are done because for $a=b=c=0$ we obtain $a+b+c=0.$

Answer (score 0):

For a real number $x$ we have
$$
 |x| \ge |1-x| \iff x \ge \frac 12 \, .
$$
This can easily be seen by squaring the left-hand side, or geometrically: Which real numbers are closer to $1$ than to zero?

Now assume that $s = a+b+c$ is not zero. Then
$$
 |a| \ge |b+c| \iff |a| \ge |s-a| \iff \left| \frac as \right| \ge \left| 1 - \frac as \right| \iff \frac as \ge \frac 12 \, .
$$
Similarly, $\frac bs \ge \frac 12$ and $\frac cs \ge \frac 12$, and adding these inequalities gives a contradiction:
$$
 1 = \frac{a+b+c}{s} \ge \frac 32 \, .
$$

---

The nice thing about this approach is that it works with *complex* numbers $a, b, c \in \Bbb C$ as well. The location of all complex numbers which are closer to one than to zero (or at the same distance) is a half-plane:
$$
|z| \ge |1-z| \iff \operatorname{Re} z \ge \frac 12 \, .
$$

Then
$$
 |a| \ge |b+c| \iff |a| \ge |s-a| \iff \left| \frac as \right| \ge \left| 1 - \frac as \right| \iff \operatorname{Re}\left(\frac as \right) \ge \frac 12 
$$
and adding these estimates for $a, b, c$ again gives a contradiction.